# Why iphone app start slowly?

Tags: iphone

i'm newbie in iphone dev, i got an issue with running an app in my iphone device. I added my provisioning profile to xcode and build successfully in my iphone (iphone 3G). But, i don't know why when the app start, **it takes 2 seconds to run the app**.my app is a sample project create by xcode (file - new project - view based application), i don't add any more code to it. i wonder that: does my provisioning profile make it slowly?
Please help me ...

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that the other applications are actually starting faster than your test case?  1-2 seconds has been the minimum startup time for applications that I've tested on the older iPhones.  For example, see James Thomson's [description of the startup time optimization he performed on PCalc](http://www.dragthing.com/blog/?p=246), where he measured that it takes ~1 second to even begin the startup process in your code.

Perhaps what you are seeing is the default image that most applications throw up on screen when they launch, making them look like they're starting faster.  They aren't actually responsive until 1-4 seconds after the launch, but they have the appearance of a fast start.

Answer (score 2):

Your app will start slow if you run it from the XCode debugger. The reason is that there is  lot of communication between the app and the debugger.

To have a realistic measure of the startup time, install the app via XCode, but start it from the iPhone's home screen.

Comment: thanks, but i stop the debugger and run it from the home screen. But it still takes 1-2 seconds to start (black screen from 1-2 seconds then app start). i've tested with other apps, they run very fast.

Comment: Have you build the app as a _Release_ version? Or is it a _Debug_ version? For a fair comparison, you should use a _Release_ version.

Comment: i've rebuild with release version, but it doesn't have any difference, app still take from 1-2 seconds to start. Do you have any idea with the provisioning profile? does it take time to parse the provisioning?

Comment: I can't tell if parsing the provisioning profile takes time or if it is even performed at startup. Is there any chance the app you compare with use a startup screen (Default.png), which looks like the running app? That way they could fake to start up very fast even though they're not faster than your app.

Answer (score 0):

Check for:

1- Your iPhone available memory, and for the background processes. You may use Mobile Substrate profiling tool (Available via Cydia only).

2- Use Instruments to check your code runs on the device, and compare it to the simulator's results

Comment: 1: my iphone is iphone 3G, have 50MB free so i don't think it is my issue. 2: my project is just a "hello world" project, so i don't see the different. Do you have any idea with provisioning profile

Answer (score 0):

Check your OS version, if it is 4.0 then you cannot do anything because it has been seen that some applications runs slowly on OS 4.0 in comparison to OS 3.x The reason for that is, iPhone 3G is not fully supported the OS 4.x. You have at least 3GS device for full support.